# What does salt and slug mean in IT?

Tags: meaning, computing, internet

salt:

> For web developers, exposing your .git folder to the world is a novice mistake. It allows anyone to download your entire source code repository, which often includes database passwords, **salts**, hashes, and third party API keys or usernames and passwords.

slug:

> Is there any REST API for retriveing all the published posts from a specific category by category **slug** or category ID?

Comment: In encryption lingo, "salt" is a random bit of nonsense fed through an encryption algorithm ahead of the text to be encrypted.  This makes the would-be eavesdropper's job much harder.  No idea what "slug" is, though.

Comment: In web publishing, is a set of [human-readable keywords associated with a post](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing)#Slug), usually appearing in the URL, to help both people and search engines get a quick grasp on what the post is about.

Comment: (And of course you don't want to *salt your slug*, that would kill it ;)

Comment: I'm not sure this belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of a salt: `#8®K1ĽĚ—:óĎíJł` (`35 56 16 174 152 75 49 188 204 151 58 243` in dec).

Example of slug: `http://www.buzzfeed.com/tasneemnashrulla/university-of-cincinnati-cancels-classes-ahead-of-grand-jury` (instead of `buzzfeed.com/article.php?page_id=67631`)

Comment: Am I understanding correctly? For example, I have `admin <=> 0, user <=> 1`,so using  `http://localhost/show?role=admin` is a slug way? slug is admin? and `http://localhost/show?role=0`, is not slug

Comment: Slug is a "method", "conversion" or "format" when you make the URL easier readable for the user. It doesn't matter what data is in your URL, you can always convert `key1=val1&key2=val2` to `key1/val1/key2/val2`. There're many good examples at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL).

Comment: Or: ``What'  ``   ``dóés, the-fox say?+ (jul 6, 2010)`` to `2010/8/6/what-does-the-fox-say`.

Answer (score 3):

'Slug' means a URL fragment. It is a term we only use where the fragment is human-readable text, such as the word 'shoes' in this URL: `http://onlineshop.com/shoes/123`. In this example, the category likely has an ID number as well as a slug, but the slug is used in the URL for the purpose of the Search Engine Optimisation of the page.

'Salt' is some random text concatenated onto the end of a password before using hashing (one-way encryption), as a security measure.

Comment: "Salt" comes first in the "plaintext" string fed into the encryption.  If it came last it would be useless.

Answer (score 1):

In cryptography, a "salt" is additional information used to encrypt things like passwords.  One technique of managing password information is to encrypt the passwords selected by users and store the encrypted version.  It the encryption method is strong enough, it is difficult to work backwards and decrypt the stored value.  Unfortunately, users tend to pick simple passwords, like proper names or familiar nouns, and hackers can simply run through a dictionary, encrypting words until they find a match.  To defeat this, a salt is added to the user-supplied password.  Of course, it's critical to keep the salt from the hackers.

The term may come from the act of adding salt to food, i.e., sprinkling an outside substance or from the mining term to add valuable ore to a mine to deceive others into thinking the mine will be productive.  In this case, the salter is trying to deceive the hacker.

For your example, the [typesetting](http://www.designtalkboard.com/glossary/pre-press/s-glossary.php) term "slug" is relevant.  It means a heading.

Comment: "Salt" applies to any encryption, not just short passwords.

Comment: Sure.  See the word "like"?